# Verificar números em uma lista e dizer se podem ser expressos como a soma de dois números primos

Tags: python-3.x

O código abaixo verifica se um número inteiro informado pode ser expresso pela soma de dois números primos:

```
def sum_of_primes(num):
  isPrime = 1
  for i in range (2,int(num/2),1):
    if(num % i == 0):
        isPrime = 0
        break
  return isPrime

num = int(input("Enter a number : "))

flag = 0
i = 2
for i in range (2,int(num/2),1):
  if(sum_of_primes(i) == 1):
    if(sum_of_primes(num-i) == 1):
        print(num,"pode ser expresso como a soma de",i,"e",num-i)
        flag = 1;
if (flag == 0):
  print(num,"não pode ser expresso como a soma de dois primos")
```

o código funciona corretamente (com exceção de quando entro com o número 5. Ele diz que não pode ser formado pelo soma de dois primos mas sabemos que pode: 2+3. Ainda não descobri porque).

O que preciso fazer é adaptar o código para que ele receba uma lista de números e que faça esta verificação na lista digitada.  Eu usei o seguinte input:

```
num = [int(n) for n in input("Digite os número: ").split()]
```

Porém não obtive o resultado esperado, ou seja, o programa não faz a verificação para todos os itens da lista digitada.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `range(2,int(num/2),1)` - quando `num` é 5, `int(num / 2)` é 2, então vc criou um `range(2,2,1)`, só que em um range o valor final não é incluso, então ele nem sequer entra no `for`. Basta trocar pra `range(2,int(num/2) + 1)` - repare também que não precisa do terceiro parâmetro, pois o valor default dele já é 1

Comment: A famosa Conjectura de Goldbach diz que **todo número PAR maior que 3 é igual a soma de dois números primos**.

Comment: perfeito com relação ao range: agora funciona com o 5.

Comment: Agora só preciso conseguir fazer a mesma verificação quando o usuário digita uma lista ao invés de um único número.

Comment: Se você já tem uma função que verifica que determinado número pode ser formado por dois primos, então você pode fazer uma outra função que percorrer os números da lista e chama a função para verificar soma de primos um a um.

Comment: O corpo dessa nova função pode ser algo tão trivial quanto `all(is_sum_of_primes(n) for n in lista)`